# разбор многомерного массива через foreach

Tags: php, foreach

Начинаю, изучать php и хочу сделать логирование ошибок.
Пытаюсь разобрать функцию debug_backtrace(), и не могу понять из-за чего он не хочет брать [0] массив для разбора, а берет [1].

```html
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [file] => C:\Openserver\domains\test_code\modules\static\main.php
            [line] => 32
            [function] => q
            [args] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SELECT * FROM `userfs` ORDER BY `id`
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [file] => C:\Openserver\domains\test_code\index.php
            [line] => 32
            [args] => Array
                (
                    [0] => C:\Openserver\domains\test_code\modules\static\main.php
                )

            [function] => include
        )

)
```

Использую вот такой foreach

```html
       $info = debug_backtrace();
        foreach ($info as $k=>$v){
            foreach ($v as $k2=>$v2){
echo "$k[0][$k2][$v2]";
                $error = date("Y-m-d H:i:s").
                    "<br>\nЗапрос: ".$query.
                    "<br>\nОшибка: ".mysqli_error($link).
                    "<br>\nВ файле: ".$k[0]['file'].$v2.
                    "<br>\nВ строке: ".$k[0]['line'].$v2.
                    "<br>\nВ функции: ".$k[0]['function'].$v2
                ;
            }
        }
```

Можете подсказать где допустил ошибку?

Comment: потому что надо изучить как работает foreach. $k - это УЖЕ ключ

Comment: Следует отметить, что данный код является бессмыслицей. выводить одни и те же данные (запрос, ошибка, и пр.) не имеет никакого смысла.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**$k** - ключ в объекте **$info**
**$v** - значение в объекте **$info** с ключом **$k**
**$k2** - ключ в объекте **$v**
**$v2** - значение в объекте **$v** с ключом **$k2**

```
   foreach ($info as $k=>$v){
        foreach ($v as $k2=>$v2){
            echo $v2;
            //$v2 = $info[$k][$k2]
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Как оказалось, мне надо было использовать `$info[0]` вместо `$k[0]`.

```
$info[0]['file'].$v2
```

Comment: ты хоть понял, что foreach тебе здесь не нужен?

Comment: Мне нужны были определенны поля для лога, а не все. Если бы надо было все, то  конечно можно было обойтись без foreach

Comment: Ты сейчас написал какую-то глупость. foreach дает тебе ВСЕ эллементы массива по определению. А вот используешь ты только один. Протри глаза уже, нельзя так тупить чудовищно.